# Query Django sin repetir resultados

Tags: django

Buenas tardes uso Django 2.0 en una aplicación para controlar asistentes a un evento, la idea es generar un informe de personas asistentes, mediante el modelo **Asistencia** sin importar que tengan mas de un registro, y que el resultado de la consulta me arroje las personas sin repetirlas.

**models.py**

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numeroDocumento = models.BigIntegerField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Asistencia(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hora = models.TimeField(default=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),editable=False)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=date.today,editable=False)
```

**views.py**

```
personas = Asistencia.objects.filter(fecha__range=[fi,ff])
```

He intentado con **distinct** pero no obtengo el resultado esperado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el distinc hay que usarlo con el vales , por ejemplo:

```
lista_personas = Asistencia.objects.filter(fecha__range=[fi,ff]).values("persona").distinc()

personas = Persona.objects.filter(pk__in=lista_personas)
```

Answer (score 0):

si lo que buscas es obtener las personas podrías realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
personas = Persona.objects.filter(asistencia__fecha__range=[fi,ff]).distinct()
```

Esto generará el JOIN con `Asistencia` y aplicará el filtro de rangos, por último aplica el `distinct` para evitar personas repetidas.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Saludos!